# Change directories

Tags: shell

I am having some trouble in doing some comands on shell.
My problem is that I want to change directories more specifically to a directory which I don't know but that contains the file named xxx. 
How can I change directly to that directory that contains that file?
If I knew the names of the directories that contained that file would be easier because I only had to use cd ~/Name of directory. 
Can anyone help me?
thanks

Comment: What operating system? What programming language? You didn't give us any background at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU `find`:

```
cd "$(find /startdir -name 'filename' -printf %h -quit)"
```

You can replace "/startdir" with any valid directory, for example `/`, `.` or `~/.

If you want to `cd` to a directory which is in the `$PATH` that contains an executable file:

```
cd "$(dirname "$(type -P "filename")")"    # Bash
```

or

```
cd "$(f=$(type -P "ksh"); echo "${f%/*}")"    # Bash
```

or

```
cd "$(dirname "$(which "filename")")"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know where a file is, go to the root of the system and **find** it:

```
cd /
find . -iname filename
```

Answer (score 1):

In several linux systems you could do:

```
$ cd `find . -name "filename" | xargs dirname`
```

But change "filename" to the file you want to find.

Answer (score 0):

BASH

```
cd `find . -name "*filename*" | head -1`
```

This is kind of a variation to Qiau answer. Finds the first file which contains the string *filename* and then change the current directory to its location.

*** is a wild card, there may be something before and/or after *filename*.